# Animations in Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular

Trying to get a fade in effect, not interested in fade out, on a picture in a component.

I works the first time the component is created but does not fire subsequently when the img src tag is changed. My understanding is this is because it only fires when the element is created.

The only way it seemed to fire was if I put the urls into an array and used ngFor. I am using standard detectchanges and cannot think of what I am doing wrong. Here is example code but I have had many attempts. I just want to change a src tag and have the animation run each time and not just the first time through ideally without using timers or removing classes.

```
    <picture class="a-image"
      (@fading.start)="onImageFadeStart($event)"
      (@fading.done)="onImageFadeDone($event)"
      [@fading]='state'
      >
      <source media="(min-width: 1024px)" srcset={{urls?.url_lg}} />
      <source media="(min-width: 640px)" srcset={{urls?.url_md}} />
      <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset={{urls?.url_sm}} />
      <img src={{urls?.url_default}} alt="a image" />
    </picture>
```

Comment: We can't see enough of what you are doing to see the issue.

Comment: What Austin said. It depends on how you change your image url really. You could try to put an *ngIf on the <picture> element so it gets replaced (thereby restarting the animation). But that involves setting the irl to null first before you do an update.

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple enough with just CSS, and a few expressions.

I've [done it here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9rv9vc?file=src/app/app.component.html) with both an ngFor and a single image.

The HTML:

```
<div>
  <img class="fade-img" 
  [ngClass]="doShowLast ? 'show' : 'hide'"    
  src="https://live.staticflickr.com/7875/47004083192_7fd9fff8c3.jpg" width="500"
  height="333" alt="Drone">

 </div>
```

And then CSS:

```
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;  
}

.fade-img {
  transition: opacity 500ms
}
```

In my TypeScript all I do is from a button click flip a value to show the button (you will likely handle this differently)

```
doShowLast = false;

switchLast(){
  this.doShowLast = !this.doShowLast;
}
```